# Pylint, how to disable rule with condition

Tags: python, pylint, pylintrc

I don't want to disable the rule for entire project, but for a known scenario. Like:

```py
class A:
   def __init__(self, creator: Callback[[],B])
```

Most of time I use

```py
x = A(lamda: Bx())
y = A(lamda: By())
```

But it always trigger `unnecessary-lambda`, but I can't remove this lambda. Since this case happens a lot, I just want to disable that rule under that condition..

Something like:

```
disable=unnecessary-lambda when-class=A
```

Or as annotation...

```py
# pylint: disable=unnecessary-lambda propagate=True
class A:
    def __init__(self, creator: Callback[[],B])
```

There is some sort way to do that?

PS:
The case happens like that:

```py
class Bx(B):
    factory = A(lambda: Bx())
```

Answer (score 1):

The lambda really is unnecessary in the code as it stands.  You can use `x = A(Bx)` instead of `x = A(lambda: Bx())`.  This would get rid of the warning.

In case this doesn't solve your problem, I will refer you to https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/message-control.html which gives various ways to disable a pylint warning in e.g. a given scope.

Comment: Well, it isn't a problem if the `x = A(Bx)` won't be a static instance inside `Bx`. At that point `Bx` does not exists and that is why the lambda is required.
As a workaround, I can instantiate `Bx.x = A(Bx)` after declaring `Bx`. That solve the problem.
But.. I will break the pattern in code. Sometimes it is just `A(lambda: Bx())`, but there are others cases where we use `A(lambda: Bz(True))`.. Mixing pattern does not looks good. But also writing `# pylint: disable=...` in each useless lambda for class A, will be a pain

Comment: I see, when wanting to do this inside the class, obviously it isn't fully resolved.  Perhaps disable the warning in the configuration file to get essentially a global disable?  Sorry, I don't have a good solution.